# Selecting one element from each innermost dimension with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a three dimensional numpy source array and a two-dimensional numpy array of indexes.

For example:

```
src = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],
                [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
idx = np.array([[0,1],
                [1,2]])
```

I'd like to get a 2d array, where each element represents the indexed value in the innermost dimension in that position:

```
array([[1,5],
       [8,12]])
```

How do I do this with numpy?

Comment: `src[:, [*range(2)]*2, idx.ravel()].ravel()[[*range(2), *range(-2, 0)]].reshape(2, 2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `np.take`, here is the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

However, you should count the index of the array after flattening all the elements. For example you should use

```py
src = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],
                [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]])
idx = np.array([[0,4],
                [7,11]])

# Wanted result
res = np.take(src, idx)
```

where `src` was regarded as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`

You can also try `np.take_along_axis`, here is the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html).

Using this method need your `src` and `idx` in same dimension, therefore, you should first **unsqueezed** the `src` and **squeeze** the `res`.

```py
# Unsqueezed the last dim
idx = np.expand_dims(idx, axis=-1)

# Squeeze the last dim
res = np.take_along_axis(src, idx, axis=2).squeeze(-1)
```

Comment: Thanks, the second method does what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [np.choose](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) method with a little reshaping:

```
np.choose(idx.reshape((1, 2, 2)), src.transpose()).reshape((2, 2))

>>>> array([[ 1,  8],
            [ 5, 12]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Direct indexing:

```
src[np.arange(2)[:, None], np.arange(2), idx]
```